# Trying to call 'this' from click event coffeescript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, coffeescript

I'm trying to something in canvas respond when clicked. I've added a mousedown event listener to the canvas, from a function, inside of a class `Board`

```
addEvents : () ->
    @.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',@.mouseDown)
mouseDown : (e) ->
    console.log(e,@)
```

The two function above are in the class `Board`, and when the canvas is clicked, i would like to return board from @, but instead it is returning the canvas.

I've tried changing the event listener/mousedown function to:

```
addEvents : () ->
    @.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',(e)->@.mouseDown(e,@))
mouseDown : (e,@) ->
    console.log(e,@)
```

but this throws an error of `unexpected PARAM_END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to have figured out, you need to use the fat arrow `=>` to bind `this` (aka `@`) lexically inside the function body.

```
class Board
  constructor: (@canvas) ->
  addEvent: ->
    @canvas.addEventListener 'mousedown', @mouseDown
  mouseDown: (event) =>       
    # handle the event here
```

Using the fat arrow for the `mouseDown` method means that `@` is defined lexically inside the function instead of at invocation... so it's the instance of the `class` that you *see* in your code instead of the receiver of the event (a DOM element).

Note that you don't need a `.` after the `@` -  you can write `@canvas` instead of  `@.canvas`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return @ from the function...

```
addEvents : () ->
    @.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',@.mouseDown)
    return @
mouseDown : (e) ->
    console.log(e,@)
```

You can still explicitly do returns in Coffee...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to that guy that deleted his answer for pushing me in the right direction,

```
@.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',(e) => @.mouseDown(e))
```

was my final solution